# Want to write an order script with linux (bash)

Tags: linux, bash

I have to write a Bash Shell Script that will take in three integer arguments and print them out from smallest to largest. I am new to linux so I am unsure about errors I am experiencing with my program. This is what I have so far, but whatever I change it never seems to work.

```
#!/bin/bash
read x y z

if [ $x -lt $y && $x -lt $z ] ; then
     if [ $y -gt $z ]; then
         echo "$x $z $y"
     else
         echo "$x $y $z"

if [ $y -lt $x && $y -lt $z ] ; then
     if [ $x -gt $z ]; then
         echo "$y $z $z"
     else
         echo "$y $x $z"

    if [ $z -lt $x && $z -lt $y ] ; then
         if [ $z -gt $y ]; then
             echo "$z $y $x"
         else
             echo "$z $x $y"
fi
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: For every `if` there should be a `fi`.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 3):

It's just one line [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) code script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $* | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -n | tr '\n' ' '
```

Comment: `echo $* | tr ' ' '\n'` can be better written as `printf "%d\n" "$@"`... Saves you a process.

Comment: @anishsane printf is better,
    printf "%d\n" "$*" | sort -n | tr '\n' ' '
It's "$*" not the "$@" ?

Comment: In this context (all arguments being just numbers), you can use `"$@"`, `$@` or `$*` but not `"$*"`...